# I am running out of SMTP Relays thrice in a week on my VPS running CentOS 6.6

Tags: smtp, cpanel, vps, whm, exim

I have a `VPS` purchased from godaddy runs `CentOS 6.6` and I have more than 150 `Joomla` websites hosted onto this. I have maximum smtp relays alloted from godaddy that is 2000 for now. I am running out of SMTP relays due to some php scripts sending out emails alot and my email queue has lacks of emails to be sent. Earlier, I was also receiving many emails to the address like *abc@xyz.com* where *xyz.com* is hosted on my server but abc is not a user/email. In this case my server was sending bounce backs which was utilizing my relays. I have resolved this issue by rejecting such emails for which user is not availabel at the time of smtp check. This solved the problem a bit. But now, everyday a new php file send lot of emails out and utilizes all of my `smtp relays`. I delete such files everytime I detect this issue but there is not any permanant solution I got yet. Anybody please help me stop this at server level, not for particular website.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this issues by disabling php mail function on your server and For the site mail, you will have to use SMTP authentication for your all site so that no one can send mail using any scripts.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. This seems really helpful. I have a query, on many of my websites there is an enquiry form which uses php mail function and it is needed to be enabled. Do you think only enabling SMTP authentication will do the job?

Comment: Yes, You can permantly reslove this spamming issues my disabled php mail function on your server, Otherwise you have to continuously monitor your logs and server queue to delete that spam mails from your server.

I will also suggest you setup CSF firewall on your server and enable Relay Tracking in configuration file  so you will get the alert if any domain OR file is sending the more than 100  mail from your server .